# easeOnBounce(jQuery) not working when entered in

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, mouseover

I am trying to get my img(.imgrow) children to bounce when I use

```
$(".imgrow").children().mouseover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            bottom: '75px'
        }, 'fast');
    });

    $(".imgrow").children().mouseout(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            bottom: '0px'
        }, 'fast');
    });
```

This is the HTML to it

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row imgrow">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6" id="p1">
                <img class="penhide" id="pen1"src="img/Penguin2.png" alt="">

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6" id="p2">
                <img class="penhide" id="pen2"src="img/Penguin2.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6" id="p3">
                <img class="penhide" id="pen3"src="img/Penguin2.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6" id="p4">
                <img class="penhide" id="pen4"src="img/Penguin2.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6" id="p5">
                <img class="penhide" id="pen5"src="img/Penguin2.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-xs-6" id="p6">
                <img class="penhide" id="pen6"src="img/Penguin2.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>`
```

Anytime I enter 'easeOnBounce' at the end like so it does not work, the entire code stops working and I have no clue what to do...

```
$(".imgrow").children().mouseover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            bottom: '75px'
        }, 'fast', 'easeOnBounce');
    });
```

After I enter that for both, or even just one, the entire code stops working all together.. All Help is appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe easeOnBounce is a valid type - http://easings.net/

Comment: I am an idiot... It is easeOutBounce, i just realized that after i posted this.. Fail

Comment: Talking through the problem to someone usually ends up with the solution presenting itself!

Comment: Okay so easeOutBounce is not working either.. How do I edit my op so I can change easeOnBounce to out